# Failed To Load ESAPI.properties Error In Java Spring Boot 2.6.7 After Updating The ESAPI Dependancy

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, esapi

Getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException; exception message was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource.
```

After updating the ESAPI dependency from 2.1.0.1 to 2.4.0.0 in one of my projects. Although i was able to remove this error in another project by removing the previous version of the dependancy when i am trying the similar approach in another project it is still giving the error. Tried maven clean install , maven update & eclipse:eclipse as well no help from these. is there any way i can find what the actual cause of this is as the current solution that i have is to clean the .m2 folder redownload the dependancy again but that is very lengthy process. Also i am not sure why the old one is conflicting with the new one when i try maven dependancy i am only seeing the newer version in the output. Although i am not using the library in this project it is coming as part of dependancy we have.

The StackTrace

```
ESAPI: WARNING: System property [org.owasp.esapi.opsteam] is not set
ESAPI: WARNING: System property [org.owasp.esapi.devteam] is not set
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\git\xyzproject\ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\XYZ) directory: C:\Users\XYZ\esapi\ESAPI.properties
ESAPI: Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
ESAPI: Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
ESAPI: SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using current thread context class loader!
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile.MultiValued not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for Validator.ConfigurationFile not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: validation.properties
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
ESAPI: Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\git\xyzproject\validation.properties
ESAPI: Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\validation.properties
ESAPI: Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\XYZ) directory: C:\Users\XYZ\esapi\validation.properties
ESAPI: Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
ESAPI: Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
ESAPI: validation.properties could not be loaded by any means. fail.. Caught java.lang.IllegalArgumentException; exception message was: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load ESAPI.properties as a classloader resource.
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.printProperties not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for Encryptor.CipherTransformation not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Encoder not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder
ESAPI: SecurityConfiguration for ESAPI.Logger not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory
```

The actual Exception that is thrown

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
```

Complete StackTrace

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1907)
at com.xyz.handleAffiliationRelationAggregationRequest(GetAffiliationJSONEndpoint.java:85)
at com.xyz$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5366cde1.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:102)
at com.xyz.common.metrics.MetricAdvice.calculateMethodMetric(MetricAdvice.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at com.xyz$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5920ce53.handleAffiliationRelationAggregationRequest(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at com.xyz.common.web.RequestFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1423)
at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:101)
at com.xyz.logging.util.JavaLogger.espiEncodeString(JavaLogger.java:278)
at com.xyz.logging.util.JavaLogger.debug(JavaLogger.java:38)
at com.xyz.tag.util.Logger.debug(Logger.java:55)
at com.xyz.tag.exception.ApplicationException.<init>(ApplicationException.java:57)
at com.xyz.tag.exception.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:126)
at com.xyz.aggregation.exception.ProviderExceptionFactory.createException(ProviderExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.xyz.aggregation.exception.ProviderExceptionFactory.createException(ProviderExceptionFactory.java:30)
at com.xyz.aggregation.exception.ExceptionUtilService.createSPSException(ExceptionUtilService.java:39)
at com.xyz.aggregation.GetAffiliationAggregationHelper.getAggregatedAffiliationRelations(GetAffiliationAggregationHelper.java:90)
at com.xyz.aggregation.GetAffiliationAggregationHelper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8448cc4c.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$$Lambda$1512/375283757.call(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:278)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport$$Lambda$1513/259319007.get(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.loadClassByStringName(ObjFactory.java:158)
at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:81)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:155)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.<init>(DefaultEncoder.java:83)
at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance(DefaultEncoder.java:67)
        ... 28 more
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It cannot find a properties file in the location it is expecting it, this has nothing to do with conflicting dependencies. Please add the **full stacktrace** instead of a snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum When we see this error generally we think for that but in my case we are not   providing / using the file anywhere in the code then how come it is working for some other project and same dependancies?

Comment: @NamanSharma I am currently struggling to integrate ESAPI with my springboot project. 
I have tried the documentation guide as well. Can you help me with a minimal example of steps that would be needed for the setup. I would really appreciate the help

Comment: @Einstein_AB I found this link usefull : [link](https://blog.katastros.com/a?ID=00750-6b758253-3217-4515-a80d-fa6952730423)

Comment: It requires a properties file to be configured, without that file it won't work. So provide the said file. Judging from this it eventually finds something and you are just triggered by the warnings...

Comment: @M.Deinum Check the updated description that's what the actual exception is that is comming from service also note this exception i am getting in my local only when the same service is deployed on server where it has only those dependancy which are required by the service it works as expected but in local as i have some other projects which use other version of this dependancy it is causing the above issue.

Comment: That error is about creating an instance **not** the loading of a properties file. As stated you are mixing things and get triggered by the warnings. If you want to add something add the **full stacktrace** as that will contain a cause (probably some mixing of versions, incompatible other things).

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Well if you read the stacktrace it is pretty clear `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory`... Apparenty you are either missing some (additional?) dependency or you are mixing different versions of that dependency. Or that class is loaded dynamically based on a property in your properties file and that name/location of the class has changed.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah that is what i am trying to say when the service is deployed on the server it picks the correct version as there are no other dependancies present apart from the one's that are declared in service, but since my local has the previous version of this dependancy it is conflicting in my local when i try to remove the depedency manually and update the project the depedency folder is created again, as i mentioned earlier that i was able to resolve this for other project by deleting the dependency manually but for some reason not working for this project.

Comment: There is no conflicting dependency... There is only one, unless you included both.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your actual exception stack trace that you present, I think this line points to the problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.logging.java.JavaLogFactory
```

(About 10 lines or so from the bottom.)

You mentioned that you had went from ESAPI 2.1.0.1 to 2.4.0.0. Back during ESAPI 2.2.1.0 (which you skipped over), we refactored the Logger class names to add support for SLF4J. So, I'm guessing that you didn't read those release notes, which is understandable. However, as a result of the refactoring, there were some required changes that needed to be made in your **ESAPI.properties** file and it looks as though you didn't make those.  Specifically, you need to  to update your `ESAPI.Logger` property with one of the new class names in your and possibly make some other related changes as discussed in https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/documentation/esapi4java-core-2.2.1.0-release-notes.txt#L128-L155 and several successive release notes. (I left that paragraph in the release notes for several releases over a couple of years, but I finally pulled it out of 2.3.0.0 because we had so much other important stuff in there that we didn't want people to skim over.)ESAPI.Logger

Anyhow, had you just used the stock configuration files from the esapi.2.4.0.0-configuration.jar, it likely would have worked, but like most people migrating, they don't think they need to update the **ESAPI.properties** file. And since the stack trace is so long, you almost have to know what you're looking for to find the root cause. But I think that should fix your problem. It if doesn't, let me know as there could always be other things wrong as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice in our case we are not defining any property in ESAPI.properties it is blank so i think we should be good as you mentioned in your answer. The problem i am facing is that after the update my project is somehow not able to dereference the older version and as i mentioned i was able to run another similar project with similar dependency structure to run fine after i manually removed the dependency from .m2 folder and re-downloaded all the required dependencies but when i tried the similar approach in another project i am still facing the same issue in my local.

Comment: It may be that someone has dumped an ESAPI.properties in one of your application jars and it is finding it that way. Try pointing to the new one via the System property org.owasp.esapi.resources, as per https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.owasp.esapi/esapi and you may be able to work around that problem.

Comment: For those who kept looking for the config files for sometime like I did:
https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/releases/download/esapi-2.5.0.0/esapi-2.5.0.0-configuration.jar

Comment: @M.Amer - Yeah, sorry about that. We try to document that under 'releases'. A long time ago, we used to bundle those default ESAPI configuration files as resources in the ESAPI jar itself, but it made them difficult to change (especially back when we used 'jarsigner' to since the ESAPI jar). It just caused more confusion than it was worth so we split it out into a separate jar. Unfortunately, I've not be able to figure out how to get the configuration jar to upload to Maven Central. :-(